# Why does MySQL not optimise this simple query and provide the result from cache?

Tags: mysql, caching, optimization

**Query :**

```
select count(a_column) from a_table where (0=0) ;
```

When I executed this query at the MySQL prompt, it took about **0.90 seconds** to provide the number of rows in the table.
When I repeated the same query, I got the result in **0.00 seconds , consistently**.
This implies that the result was cached against this query.

Now I changed the condition to `where (1=1)` , it took **0.65 seconds** to execute.
When I repeated this new query, I got the result in **0.00 seconds , consistently**.
This again implies that the result was cached against this new query.

The `where` clause is unnecessary, and can be removed. If the result was cached against this optimised query, then only the first execution should take more time , and every repeat should have got the results in 0.00 seconds, even when I change N in `where (N=N)`, but it seems that MySQL did not do this optimisation.

**Does MySQL optimise such queries ?
What is the explanation of my mini experiments ?**

I am using MySQL 5.0.77 on CentOS 5.2, which might be old, and this issue might not exist in newer releases, but I am more interested in knowing the reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html).

Quoting the manual:

> Incoming queries are compared to those in the query cache before
>   parsing, so the following two queries are regarded as different by the
>   query cache:
>
> - SELECT * FROM tbl_name
> - Select * from tbl_name
>
> Queries must be exactly the same (byte for byte) to be seen as
>   identical. In addition, query strings that are identical may be
>   treated as different for other reasons. Queries that use different
>   databases, different protocol versions, or different default character
>   sets are considered different queries and are cached separately.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.
Is there any DB Server (freeware or commercial) which does such simple optimisations ?
What about optimising joins and subqueries ?
I always thought that DB software would be intelligent and would aggressively optimise queries (eg like C compilers optimising loops and inline functions etc) and I was shocked when I saw that even this simple query was not optimised.

Comment: @Prem, if you're asking the same thing from the database, then the question should be the same. For performance, MySQL caches the query and the results, not anything in between. If you ask the same question, it just feeds you the same results, saving tons of load on your server. It still gets optimized, the first time through.